# How to read an excel file without change date format

Tags: r

I try to read in an excel file which contain date like below:

I would like to keep as is not to changed them into yyyy-mm-dd formte. However when I use `read_excel`, it will auto change the date format. any way to keep as is? tried col_types="text" and did not work. it will change them into 5 digit numbers.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: After reading the file, convert dates to text with `format(...,'%d%b%Y')`

Comment: I have so many cols. Try to find a way to avoid reformat them.

Comment: Then use `library(dplyr); data %>% mutate(across(where(lubridate::is.Date), format, '%d%b%Y'))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that can be considered. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

dir_Path <- "D:\\"
excel_File <- "test_File.xlsx"
path_Excel_File <- paste0(dir_Path, excel_File)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets() 
nb_Sheets <- Sheets$count() 

list_DF_By_Sheet <- list()

for(l in 1 : nb_Sheets)
{
  mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
  
  for(i in 1 : 2)
  {
    for(j in 1 : 2)
    {
      mat[i, j] <- Sheets[[l]]$Cells(i,j)$Text()    
    }
  }
  
  list_DF_By_Sheet[[l]] <- mat
}

list_DF_By_Sheet

[[1]]
     [,1]         [,2]        
[1,] "2005-01-01" "2008-01-01"
[2,] "01-01-2006" "01/01/2009"

[[2]]
     [,1]         [,2]        
[1,] "2001-01-01" "2003-01-01"
[2,] "2002-01-01" "2004-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably You can try this

```r
library(openxlsx)
```

*Read in the Excel file*

```r
data <- read.xlsx("your_file.xlsx", sheet = 1, header = TRUE)
```

*Specify the column with dates as a date format*

```r
data$date_column <- as.Date(data$date_column, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.the problem is I do not want the  date variables to change format. during the read in process. In fact I have multiple data variables in different format in my raw data. I want to keep them as is, in stead of standardize them.